# update server .net version to 7.0

Tags: .net

I'm using PuTTY to connect to my server.

I want to update my .net version in my server. However, .net7.0 is not existing. Only available until .net 6.0.

I have tried these commands but none of time works:

- dotnet-runtime-7.0
- aspdotnet-rumtime.7.0
- sudo yum install dotnet-sdk-7.0

ref:

- https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/7.0
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu

Comment: _"However, .net7.0 is not existing"_ - can you please elaborate?

Comment: @GuruStron when i run those commands, it stated those package where not available. However, my project is .net 7.0 which requireds a min vers of .net7 to run><

Comment: So it is not the .net7.0 missing but concreate package manager does not have it. So you have following options 1) install using another package manager which have it 2) add it to package manager used 3) install manually.

Comment: @GuruStron I have tried the above command to install but not working. any idea why?

Comment: Why do you expect them to work? Where have you seen them? Have you tried reading instructions in the second link?

Comment: Finally you can always package your app as self-contained and then you will not install anything.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use existing and supported tools from MSFT to install/update your dotnet runtimes.

This will download and install to `~/.dotnet` dotnet 7.0:

```
wget https://dot.net/v1/dotnet-install.sh -O dotnet-install.sh
chmod +x ./dotnet-install.sh
./dotnet-install.sh --channel 7.0
```

among other things:

> ```
> dotnet-install: Installed version is 7.0.400
> dotnet-install: Adding to current process PATH: `/home/user/.dotnet`.
> Note: This change will be visible only when sourcing script.
> ```

references:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-install-script
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-scripted-manual#scripted-install